# jQuery Dialog Squeeze Height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, css, jquery-attributes

I am trying to squeeze the entire height of a dialog box I created with jQuery UI down to a height of 0px once the dialog is created. I cannot use the dialog's "height" property, and set that to 0, as I need **everything** to be squished down.

Here is a watered-down version of my code. Could some one point out where I am going wrong?

```
$('<div class="myDialog" title="Test"></div>').dialog({
  'create' : function() {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'height' : '0'
    });
  })
});
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not sure why you need `height == 0`, why don't you just do `.hide()`?

Comment: I'm setting the height = 0 because I want to make the entire dialog grow to regular size. I've checked into the effects library, but none of them do _exactly_ what I want, so I'm doing it manually.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `widget` do this:

```
$(this).dialog('widget').css({
  'height' : '0'
});
```

This edits the dialog as a whole.

Comment: wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, Neal. That does leave me with one last question. Doing that made it look like a little bar. Is there a way I can shrink it more, leaving me the option to animate it to regular size, later?

Comment: @spryno, why dont you just do `dialog('close')` and do `dialog('open')` later?

Comment: We'll here is my dilemma. I'd like the dialog to look as though it is flying from the bottom of browser window, then resting at the center of the screen. I was thinking of making it 0px in height, placing it at the bottom of the screen (since I can't go lower the window, if the page is too short), and sizing it to 200px. Once that is at full size, I'd slide it to the center of the screen. I'm hoping the combo of those two effects will looks like it is sliding from the bottom of the screen. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: so say that in your question. right now i have answered your OP